# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv2D' with these attrs

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, anaconda, cudnn

new to this may be something dumb but cant get conv2d to run

---

windows 10

anaconda 4.2.13

python 3.5.2

C:\windows\system32>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Sep__3_19:05:48_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44

cudnn 5.1

TensorFlow 0.12

---

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

graph1 = tf.Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    f=tf.constant(   np.ones(10).reshape(1,1,-1,1)   )
    g=tf.constant(   np.ones(3).reshape(1,-1,1,1)   )
    conv1=tf.nn.conv2d( f,g, strides=[1,1,1,1] , padding="SAME",name="conv1")

with tf.Session(graph=graph1) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(f))
    print(sess.run(g))
    print(sess.run(conv1))
    sess.close()
```

results in:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv2D' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU,GPU], Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]

    [[Node: conv = Conv2D[T=DT_DOUBLE, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Const, Const_1)]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change two lines to

```
f=tf.constant(   np.ones(10).reshape(1,1,-1,1).astype(np.float32)   )
g=tf.constant(   np.ones(3).reshape(1,-1,1,1).astype(np.float32)   )
```

Otherwise those nodes take on default numpy type of `float64`, which doesn't have `Conv2D` kernel

Comment: Thanks! I spent too long on that, but the docs said it took 64bit on the tensorflow site.

Comment: You are right, that's a bit confusing, sent https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/6485 to fix